# Use $skip in node red

Tags: mongodb, node-red

I am trying to display 25 records at a time. I tried passing `$skip` but it does not seem to work.

I have tried something like this:

`msg.skip = {$skip: context.global.rawData.skip};`

`msg.skip` shows following: `{ $skip: 25 }`

#### Update:

I tried something similar to [this](https://medium.com/@motiooon/workflow-based-visual-programming-with-node-red-81b720359c7).

Here is how my function looks

```
context.global.count = context.global.count + 25;
msg.skip = context.global.count;

msg.limit = 25;

return msg;
```

I just realised I am using `mongo node` from [`node-red-bluemix-nodes`](http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-bluemix-nodes).

Comment: You've not explained what's not working. Are you getting more than 25 records or is it always returning the first 25 records. But that should work fine assuming it's being fed to a Mongo in node

Comment: it is always returning first 25 records. Yes it is fed to mongodb node with operation field as `find`

Answer (score 0):

From the [README](http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-node-mongodb) for the mongodb node:

> Optionally, you may also (via a function) set
>
> - a msg.projection object to constrain the returned fields,
> - a msg.sort object,
> - a msg.limit number,
> - a msg.skip number.

So `msg.skip` should be `25` not `{ $skip: 25 }`

Comment: No luck with that too!

Comment: @Freddy Just to confirm the answer should work, refer to the github implementation [here](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-nodes/blob/master/storage/mongodb/66-mongodb.js#L210), `msg.skip` should be a number.

Comment: I am doing something similar to this https://medium.com/@motiooon/workflow-based-visual-programming-with-node-red-81b720359c7. (I can update my question with more details if required)

Comment: I am using [node-red-bluemix-nodes](http://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-bluemix-nodes) for mongodb node. In info section there is no mention of `msg.skip`

Comment: Actually I've just had a look, those nodes are different, they need updating to match the standalone node. You should open an issue against it's git repo